# Change color in ToggleButtonBar on mouse over

Tags: apache-flex

I have a ToggleButtonBar, 
Exist any way in Flex to change font color on mouse over in a ToggleButtonBar?

I try using hover in ToggleButtonBar style and:
`mouseOver="buttonBar.setStyle('color','#FFFFFF');"`

But that dosen't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

[Flex help? Change text colour on MouseOver?](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-158965.html)

will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create a custom skin for ButtonBarButton and set it in styles.  Within your skin there would be states, one of them being 'hovered' or something like that.  There you can set the color of your label depending on that state:

```
<s:Label color.hovered="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it using css:

```
mx|ButtonBarButton
{
    textRollOverColor: #FFFFFF;
}
```